# rtsenable does not work as expected

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have written a simple winform application to read data received to a RS232 DE9 serial port from a micro controller. I need to control when data should be sent so I control the RtsEnable property for that. Program structure is similar to something like this.

```
byte[] data = new byte[serialPort1.BytesToRead];
serialport1.RtsEnable = true;

private void serialPort1_DataReceived(object sender,
System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    serialPort1.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
    serialport1.RtsEnable = false;
    this.Invoke(new EventHandler(ProcessData));
    serialport1.RtsEnable = true;
}
```

Now, the problem is simple. When the RtsEnable is set true at first, it is actually not  set to true. Sure when I debug, it shows as RtsEnable = true. But when I check the voltages in my circuit, RTs is still not high.

I don't think it is something wrong with my circuit as I checked voltages output at the serail port manually. So, it's got to be something with my code, I think.

Any idea as to why this is?
Thanks in advance

Comment: If you write a program that just loops and enables and disables RTS, do you see any line toggle?  Often people are confused between RTS and CTS because you cross-connect RTS from one side to CTS on the other device.  Also, are you sure that enable should be high voltage, or could the signal be active low?

Comment: For q1, I did my testing without sending any data. So, the data_received event is not yet triggered and RtsEnable must be true. So, no toggles yet. For q2, According to what I read about serial port, RTS gets high when the port is open. So, it must output a high voltage

Answer (score -1):

The RtsEnable does not set the RTS, it only enables it to be set. 
To set (pull Low) the RTS (and similarly the DTR), you need to set your handshake to XonXoff.

Example:

```
   private void btnReset_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        comm.MycomPort.RtsEnable = true;
        comm.MycomPort.Handshake = System.IO.Ports.Handshake.XOnXOff;
        comm.MycomPort.RtsEnable = false;
    }
```

This will momentary pull the RTS Low (or DTR if you use MycomPort.DtrEnable)
It will stay low until disabled, so you could add a timer to keep it low for any duration.

Comment: If the port is already open, toggling `DtrEnable` or `RtsEnable` *does* cause the pin to change immediately.